# finding occurences of Dataframe column of max value in multi-index case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a set of data for which I am trying to assess the influence of each parameter. To do so, my first idea is to try and compute the probability of my parameter value yielding the best outcome when locking all other parameters, or more generally to be in the best x%. Let's look at an example to make it clearer :

My data looks like this (but with more levels):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]]
np.random.seed(123)

columns_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2,9), columns = columns_index, index=['feature1', 'feature2'])
```

which should yield you the following :

```
first            a                             b                      \
second           1         2         3         1         2         3   
feature1  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  0.551315  0.719469  0.423106   
feature2  0.392118  0.343178  0.729050  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044   
first            c                      
second           1         2         3  
feature1  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  
feature2  0.737995  0.182492  0.175452
```

Now, if i am interested at 'feature2', and wants to check the influence of 'first', I can do this :

```
df.loc['feature2'].groupby('second').max()
Out[272]: 
second
1    0.737995
2    0.343178
3    0.729050
```

Now, the question is, how can I get the following :

The max is obtain with :

- 'first' = c for 'second'= 1
- 'first' = a for 'second'= 2
- 'first' = a for 'second'= 3

so I would like to compute :
a : 66.66%
b : 0%
c : 33.33%

Hope this is clear enough. I am also very interested to hear of any better idea to check the influence of the different parameters if you have an idea.

Thanks !

Comment: Im not getting how the max should be obtained. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: the max is obtain as per my ....max() line of code. What I want is to know which value of the 'first' level gives me this max.

Comment: But there are two` 'first' = c for 'second'= 1` is that a typo?

Comment: yes, was a typo, I corrected it, thanks

Comment: Now the answer is simple. Hope my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.idxmax` to get the index i.e

```
df.loc['feature2'].groupby(level=1).idxmax()
```

```
second
1    (c, 1)
2    (a, 2)
3    (a, 3)
```

Comment: nice and easy, now I just need to find how to get the ratios of 'a' and 'c' in that array, but I should be able to do that on my own, thanks !

Comment: Glad can help. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this ..

```
df.stack().loc['feature2'].stack().groupby(level='second').apply(lambda x : x[x==x.max()])
Out[805]: 
second  second  first
1       1       c        0.737995
2       2       a        0.343178
3       3       a        0.729050
```